# How to stop form being submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm using an asp.net webform page.  I have some javascript that checks if some dynamically generated fields have values and then displays a message if not.  The problem is that I haven't found a way to stop the form from being submitted when this check fails.

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" runat="server" onsubmit="finalCheck();">
```

I've tried button and input types:

```
<button type="submit">submit</button>

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

The finalCheck() method always executes and does return false.  But the form goes anyways.

Is there something else I need to do to prevent the form from being submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the event handler has to return the value from the function that it calls:

```
onsubmit="return finalCheck();"
```

Comment: Short and sweet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

write your html like this:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" runat="server" onsubmit="finalCheck(event);">
```

then into your `finalCheck(event)` write this, on the first line for good practices:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

that will stop the submit and you can add more code after the `preventDefault` function to process the form data

Answer (score 0):

The event handler function needs to return false. That function is `onsubmit`, not `finalCheck`.

```
onsubmit="return finalCheck();"
```

If you were using modern code, you could call `preventDefault` on the event object instead.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', finalCheck);

function finalCheck(event) {
    var myForm = this;
    // do stuff
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```